# With Angular, how do I bind `input` text in an `ng-repeat` `div` to another `div` in another `ng-repeat`?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to make an Angular-driven page where `input` tags are bound to `h3` tags in other DIVs.

Here's what my HTML looks like (with [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/CD2kcfdSpPMqc70bu7ll/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.square {
            background-color: #ccc;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app=    angular.module("myApp",[]);
        app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
            $scope.items=   [
                {value: ''}
            ];
            $scope.squares= [
                {value:''}
            ];

            $scope.addSomething=    function(){
                $scope.items.push({value:''});
                $scope.squares.push({value:''});
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button id="button" ng-click="addSomething()">click me</button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Headline" ng-model="item.value">
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="square in squares">
     <div class="square">
        <h3>{{item.value}}</h3>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem: The stuff I type into the `input` tag does not show up into corresponding `h3` tags. When I type into the first `input` tag, I want the words written to appear in the first `h3` tag, and so on for the second, third, etc... But this does not happen.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Depends on if you want to update the `value` in `squares` array when it is changed in  `item.value`. Why are you creating duplicate arrays in first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `input` to bind to the `h3` tag you must bind them to the same array .i.e you don't need both a `items` array and a `squares` array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  div.square {
   background-color: #ccc;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   margin: 10px;
  }
 </style>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var app= angular.module("myApp",[]);
  app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
   $scope.items= [
    {value: ''}
   ];

   $scope.addSomething= function(){
    $scope.items.push({value:''});
   };
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button id="button" ng-click="addSomething()">click me</button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Headline" ng-model="item.value">
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="square">
     <h3>{{item.value}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```